# Why the following Golang code doesn't run?

Tags: go

This code runs and gives a random number from 0 to 999:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    fmt.Println(rand.Intn(999))
}
```

But the following code refuses to run and gives an error

**Code:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    r := rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    fmt.Println(r.Intn(999))
}
```

**Error message:**

> rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano()) used as value

Note: I'm new to stackOverflow, so if the question isn't according to the rules or standards, please forgive me.

Comment: `rand.Seed` does not return anything. It only initializes the default pseudo random numbers generator. Using this seed, you'll simply call `rand.Intn`, not `r.Intn`

Comment: I believe that `r := rand.Intn(999)` after initializing with `rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())` should do the trick.

Comment: Matei, no. The doc is both very simple and pretty clear ! Either you use the global generator, or you initialize a named generator.

Answer (score 3):

`rand.Seed` doesn't return any value, its a void function.

Answer (score 1):

From godoc

> Seed uses the provided seed value to initialize the generator to a
>   deterministic state. Seed should not be called concurrently with any
>   other Rand method.

That means, that it set some seed for generating random numbers and don't return anything, but you tried to use it as some value

Answer (score 0):

`rand.Seed` “sets up” `rand.Intn`, if you will. When you call `rand.Seed`, it creates a seed that can be used *later* with `rand.Intn`. `rand.Intn` returns a value, so

```
rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
fmt.Println(rand.Intn(999))
```

works. But since `rand.Seed` does *not* return a value, calling `rand.Intn` on it returns an error.